# Formulate needed in excel to check if child will be 18 in the next 6 months

Tags: excel

Good day.

A friend of mine is a social worker in the UK and she would like to know if there is a formula in Excel to check if a child will be turning 18 in the next 6 months or not?

an example:
In the UK, if you are under 18, then one process is followed. But if you are over 18, then another process is followed to protect the child. However, it is a crucial for them to find out that if a case come in TODAY, will the child be 18 in the next 6 months or not? This answer will determine if the process to help the child the best possible way.

They have a database of many children and would like to run this formula to check which cases should be amended as kids turn 18 in the next 6 months

Answer (score 0):

Look at the TODAY() and [EDATE functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edate-function-1586b161-4361-4a6d-939b-9d96eae962a8). Eighteen years is 216 months. If the birthdate is less than or equal to `EDATE(TODAY(), -216)` then the person is 18 or over. If the birthdate is greater than `EDATE(TODAY(), -216)` but less than or equal to `EDATE(TODAY(), -210)` then they are nearing their 18th birthday.

With the birth date in B2,

```
=if(b2<=EDATE(TODAY(), -216), "18+", if(AND(b2>EDATE(TODAY(), -216), b2<=EDATE(TODAY(), 210)), "within 6 months", "child/teen"))
```

The TODAY() function is considered volatile and will refresh on every calculation cycle of the entire workbook.

Answer (score -1):

Two steps:
- Add six months to date: =DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+6,DAY(A1))
- Convert date to age: =DATEDIF(A1,NOW(),"y")

after that you can use conditional formatting.

Comment: put a date in cell A1